# how to use regular expressions with the command find to filter the path?

Tags: find, regular-expression

I have a set of directories like this:

```
/level1/user01/dir01
/level1/user01/dir02
/level1/user01/dir03
/level1/user01/dir04
/level1/user02/dir01
/level1/user02/dir02
/level1/user02/dir03
/level1/user02/dir04
/level1/user03/dir01
/level1/user03/dir02
/level1/user03/dir03
/level1/user03/dir04
```

I want to use find to search files with the extension .oz in the directory dir02 of each user

I can use

```
find /level1/ -name "*.oz"
```

but I just want to search only inside the directories dir02

This doesn't work

```
find /level1/"[a-z][0-9]"/dir02 -name "*.oz"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specify multiple directories in the first argument, then this is just dependent on your shell. So, in bash and zsh and similar (csh and tcsh?), you would just use a shell glob. The shell expands this glob into the multiple directories that you are interested in, and feeds them to `find`, which can take multiple arguments.

```
find /level1/*/dir02 -name "*.oz"
```

A few additional points:

- The syntax here is a glob, not a regex.
- Your regex was wrong anyway. (Ignoring the quoting) it should have been `/level1/[a-z]*[0-9]*/dir02`. Note the `*`s.
- Another option is `-path`, see `man find`, but that's more convoluted than just using shell globs.

Comment: You are welcome, @user3333911 .  If this answer has solved your question, please click the tick on the left to accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution using `find` with `-path`:

```
$ find /level1 -type f -path "/level1/user??/dir02/*.oz" -print
```

This will print the paths of all regular files whose whose (complete) path matches `/level1/user??/dir02/*.oz`.

If you know that the files are in the `dir02` directory (and not in a subdirectory thereof), then this will list them:

```
printf '%s\n' /level1/user??/dir02/*.oz
```